# WPF double animation completed event firing twice

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events, animation

I can't understand why the double animation event is firing twice. The rich text box gets updated on the completed method. When it is faded out, I change the text from queue. Then animation begins again. When queue is empty, it replenishes with new data. But because the event is firing twice, it skips some of the texts.

```
Private Sub CreateNewsAnimation()
    fadingNewsAnimation.From = 0
    fadingNewsAnimation.To = 1
    fadingNewsAnimation.AutoReverse = True
    fadingNewsAnimation.Duration = New Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(newsDuration))
    AddHandler fadingNewsAnimation.Completed, AddressOf fadingNewsAnimation_Completed
    RTBoxNewsBottom.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, fadingNewsAnimation)
End Sub

Private Sub fadingNewsAnimation_Completed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If enableEvent = True Then
        If m_NewsQueue.Count > 0 Then
            Using newsMemStream As New IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.[Default].GetBytes(m_NewsQueue.Dequeue()))
                RTBoxNewsBottom.Selection.Load(newsMemStream, DataFormats.Rtf)
                RTBoxNewsBottom.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, fadingNewsAnimation)
            End Using
        Else
            PopulateNewsQueue()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: every time you call `CreateNewsAnimation()` its going to create a new Completed event handler, you will need to remove any existing handlers in that method if you don't want duplicate calls.

Comment: I am calling the method in Window Initialized event and it is also firing twice.